# Bash completion inside backticks or $() using complete

Tags: bash, backticks, bash-completion

Consider this one-liner to activate bash completion for `foobar`:

```
complete -F _known_hosts foobar
```

This shows a list of completion options for

```
> foobar <TAB> <TAB>
```

but not for

```
> $(foobar <TAB> <TAB>
```

or

```
> `foobar <TAB> <TAB>
```

I think it makes a lot of sense to have tab completion for expressions that are inside backticks or $(). How can I make this work?

Comment: I think the problem is that programmable completion occurs before the shell has done any other parsing; the command name to the completion system is `$(foobar`, not `foobar`. Putting a space before `foobar` doesn't help, because then the command name looks like `$(`. Something like `ls && foobar <TAB> <TAB>` works, so there might be some minimal parsing or special casing; this might be a feature request for `bash` 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (to complete the filename i.e. you have entered some characters

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (to list possible filenames - do note; there are 2 +)

(I was searching for an answer to this question for a long time; then got this from bash man page :-))

Answer (score 1):

Bash completion inside back ticks or $() is called "command substitution".

So it looks similar to a few other questions:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152328/bash-tab-completion-fails-inside-of-command-substitution

https://askubuntu.com/questions/571544/bash-tab-completion-bash-unexpected-eof-while-looking-for-matching-bash/576983#576983

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152328/bash-tab-completion-fails-inside-of-command-substitution

For Debian-based linux operating systems like Ubuntu, the problem is a known bug from the bash-completion application: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions

You can report an issue here:

https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/issues

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the command completion, then you can do the following:

1) Open the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

2) Go to the function `_quote_readline_by_ref`.

3) Replace the line `[[ ${!2} == \$* ]] && eval $2=${!2}` with `[[ ${!2} == \$\'* ]] && eval $2=${!2}`.

4) Save the changes and exit.

After this, If you open a new tab and start typing command inside quotes or `$()`, the command will get completed or shows the possibility as it happens normally.
See the example below:

```
[22:57]✓ -> echo $(ls
ls           lsblk        lscpu        lshw         lsipc        lslogins
lsof         lspcmcia     lsusb        lsattr
```

Let me know if you face any problems.

Comment: I tried it, and unfortunately it made no difference (your example also works for me without the patch, and with the patch my use-case still doesn't work).

Comment: I don't think there is any direct way. I guess you may need to write your own program to enable such feature and provide to the open source world :)